# О слове "распинаться"

Tags: этимология

"Распинаться" - много говорить о чем-то, часто попусту. Интересно было бы узнать происхождение этого слова - как оно связано со словом "распятие"?
Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А если сравнить выражения  "распинаться" и "растекаться мыслию по древу": «Боян вещий, если кому хотяше песнь творити, то растекашется мыслию по древу, серым волком по земле, сизым орлом под облака». Распинаться - это растягиваться, похоже на "растекаться", одна приставка РАЗ - то есть во все стороны. И хотя в одном случае - это полет мысли, а в другом - пустословие, общим свойством является долгая и вдохновенная речь оратора.

Answer (score 4):

Из словаря Ушакова :
*Распинать* - несов. к *распять*.
*Распинаться* - страд. к *распинать*.

> Толковый словарь Ушакова
> РАСПИНАТЬСЯ 
> распинаюсь, распинаешься, несов. 1. Страд. к распинать. 2. за кого-что. **Хлопотать, прилагать большие усилия, тратить много сил ради кого-н. или ради достижения чего-н.** (разг. фам.). А я еще распиналась за вас перед отцом! Мельников-Печерский.

Обычное значение : с чувством что-то проповедовать, объяснять, доказывать и тд.  Тратить время и силы, даже как бы страдать, *самораспинаясь* - здесь ироничная ссылка на "распятие праведника"...

> П. Д. Боборыкин. Воспоминания (1906-1913) Но никто до него так не распинался за молодые русские таланты.